# Unable to connect to my EventStore docker container

Tags: networking, windows

This is my first attempt at setting up docker containers. I've managed to create a SQL Server container that I can connect to, but I've been struggling for more than a month to get my EventStore connected.

The site only provides instructions for a Linux image, so I had to create my own. I downloaded Eventstore, and created my image with this command :

`docker build -t eventstore_5.0.10:latest .`

I then created docker-compose.yaml with this configuration :

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  eventstore.db:
    image: eventstore/eventstore:release-v5
    environment:
      - EVENTSTORE_CLUSTER_SIZE=1
      - EVENTSTORE_RUN_PROJECTIONS=All
      - EVENTSTORE_START_STANDARD_PROJECTIONS=True
      - EVENTSTORE_DB=/var/lib/eventstore-data
      - EVENTSTORE_INDEX=/var/lib/eventstore-index
      - EVENTSTORE_LOG=/var/log/eventstore
      - EVENTSTORE_EXT_TCP_PORT=1113
      - EVENTSTORE_EXT_HTTP_PORT=2113
    ports:
      - "1113:1113"
      - "2113:2113"
    volumes:
      - type: volume
        source: eventstore-volume-data
        target: /var/lib/eventstore-data
      - type: volume
        source: eventstore-volume-index
        target: /var/lib/eventstore-index
      - type: volume
        source: eventstore-volume-logs
        target: /var/log/eventstore

volumes:
  eventstore-volume-data:
  eventstore-volume-index:
  eventstore-volume-logs:
```

When I spin up the container, EventStore starts up fine :

```
[01288,01,07:43:33.783]
2024-01-15 09:43:33 "ES VERSION:"             "5.0.10.0" ("oss-v5.0.10"/"6b9af2bc4fcd85c12c01fb115110ff6ccc5d3bfd", "Thu, 11 Mar 2021 14:39:
2024-01-15 09:43:33 08 +0100")
2024-01-15 09:43:33 MODIFIED OPTIONS:
2024-01-15 09:43:33 
2024-01-15 09:43:33         EXT HTTP PORT:            2114 (Command Line)
2024-01-15 09:43:33         EXT TCP PORT:             1114 (Command Line)
2024-01-15 09:43:33 
2024-01-15 09:43:33 DEFAULT OPTIONS:
2024-01-15 09:43:33 
2024-01-15 09:43:33         HELP:                     False (<DEFAULT>)
2024-01-15 09:43:33         VERSION:                  False (<DEFAULT>)
2024-01-15 09:43:33         LOG:                      C:\EventStore\logs (<DEFAULT>) 
2024-01-15 09:43:33         CONFIG:                   <empty> (<DEFAULT>)
2024-01-15 09:43:33         DEFINES:                  <empty> (<DEFAULT>)
2024-01-15 09:43:33         WHAT IF:                  False (<DEFAULT>)
2024-01-15 09:43:33         START STANDARD PROJECTIONS: False (<DEFAULT>)
2024-01-15 09:43:33         DISABLE HTTP CACHING:     False (<DEFAULT>)
2024-01-15 09:43:33         MONO MIN THREADPOOL SIZE: 10 (<DEFAULT>)
2024-01-15 09:43:33         INT IP:                   127.0.0.1 (<DEFAULT>)
2024-01-15 09:43:33         EXT IP:                   127.0.0.1 (<DEFAULT>)
2024-01-15 09:43:33         INT HTTP PORT:            2112 (<DEFAULT>)
2024-01-15 09:43:33         INT TCP PORT:             1112 (<DEFAULT>)
2024-01-15 09:43:33         INT SECURE TCP PORT:      0 (<DEFAULT>)
2024-01-15 09:43:33         EXT SECURE TCP PORT ADVERTISE AS: 0 (<DEFAULT>)
2024-01-15 09:43:33         EXT SECURE TCP PORT:      0 (<DEFAULT>)
2024-01-15 09:43:33         EXT IP ADVERTISE AS:      <empty> (<DEFAULT>)
2024-01-15 09:43:33         EXT TCP PORT ADVERTISE AS: 0 (<DEFAULT>)
2024-01-15 09:43:33         EXT HTTP PORT ADVERTISE AS: 0 (<DEFAULT>)
2024-01-15 09:43:33         INT IP ADVERTISE AS:      <empty> (<DEFAULT>)
2024-01-15 09:43:33         INT SECURE TCP PORT ADVERTISE AS: 0 (<DEFAULT>)
2024-01-15 09:43:33         INT TCP PORT ADVERTISE AS: 0 (<DEFAULT>)
2024-01-15 09:43:33         INT HTTP PORT ADVERTISE AS: 0 (<DEFAULT>)
2024-01-15 09:43:33         INT TCP HEARTBEAT TIMEOUT: 700 (<DEFAULT>)
2024-01-15 09:43:33         EXT TCP HEARTBEAT TIMEOUT: 1000 (<DEFAULT>)
2024-01-15 09:43:33         INT TCP HEARTBEAT INTERVAL: 700 (<DEFAULT>)
2024-01-15 09:43:33         EXT TCP HEARTBEAT INTERVAL: 2000 (<DEFAULT>)
2024-01-15 09:43:33         GOSSIP ON SINGLE NODE:    False (<DEFAULT>)
2024-01-15 09:43:33         CONNECTION PENDING SEND BYTES THRESHOLD: 10485760 (<DEFAULT>)
2024-01-15 09:43:33         CONNECTION QUEUE SIZE THRESHOLD: 50000 (<DEFAULT>)
2024-01-15 09:43:33         STREAM INFO CACHE CAPACITY: 100000 (<DEFAULT>)
2024-01-15 09:43:33         FORCE:                    False (<DEFAULT>)
2024-01-15 09:43:33         CLUSTER SIZE:             1 (<DEFAULT>)
2024-01-15 09:43:33         NODE PRIORITY:            0 (<DEFAULT>)
2024-01-15 09:43:33         MIN FLUSH DELAY MS:       2 (<DEFAULT>)
2024-01-15 09:43:33         COMMIT COUNT:             -1 (<DEFAULT>)
2024-01-15 09:43:33         PREPARE COUNT:            -1 (<DEFAULT>)
2024-01-15 09:43:33         ADMIN ON EXT:             True (<DEFAULT>)
2024-01-15 09:43:33         STATS ON EXT:             True (<DEFAULT>)
2024-01-15 09:43:33         GOSSIP ON EXT:            True (<DEFAULT>)
2024-01-15 09:43:33         DISABLE SCAVENGE MERGING: False (<DEFAULT>)
2024-01-15 09:43:33         SCAVENGE HISTORY MAX AGE: 30 (<DEFAULT>)
2024-01-15 09:43:33         DISCOVER VIA DNS:         True (<DEFAULT>)
2024-01-15 09:43:33         CLUSTER DNS:              fake.dns (<DEFAULT>)
2024-01-15 09:43:33         CLUSTER GOSSIP PORT:      30777 (<DEFAULT>)
2024-01-15 09:43:33         GOSSIP SEED:              <empty> (<DEFAULT>)
2024-01-15 09:43:33         STATS PERIOD SEC:         30 (<DEFAULT>)
2024-01-15 09:43:33         CACHED CHUNKS:            -1 (<DEFAULT>)
2024-01-15 09:43:33         READER THREADS COUNT:     4 (<DEFAULT>)
2024-01-15 09:43:33         CHUNKS CACHE SIZE:        536871424 (<DEFAULT>)
2024-01-15 09:43:33         MAX MEM TABLE SIZE:       1000000 (<DEFAULT>)
2024-01-15 09:43:33         HASH COLLISION READ LIMIT: 100 (<DEFAULT>)
2024-01-15 09:43:33         DB:                       C:\EventStore\data (<DEFAULT>)
2024-01-15 09:43:33         INDEX:                    <empty> (<DEFAULT>)
2024-01-15 09:43:33         MEM DB:                   False (<DEFAULT>)
2024-01-15 09:43:33         SKIP DB VERIFY:           False (<DEFAULT>)
2024-01-15 09:43:33         WRITE THROUGH:            False (<DEFAULT>)
2024-01-15 09:43:33         UNBUFFERED:               False (<DEFAULT>)
2024-01-15 09:43:33         CHUNK INITIAL READER COUNT: 5 (<DEFAULT>)
2024-01-15 09:43:33         RUN PROJECTIONS:          None (<DEFAULT>)
2024-01-15 09:43:33         PROJECTION THREADS:       3 (<DEFAULT>)
2024-01-15 09:43:33         WORKER THREADS:           5 (<DEFAULT>)
2024-01-15 09:43:33         PROJECTIONS QUERY EXPIRY: 5 (<DEFAULT>)
"024-01-15 09:43:33         FAULT OUT OF ORDER PROJECTIONS: False (<DEFAULT>)
2024-01-15 09:43:33         INT HTTP PREFIXES:        <empty> (<DEFAULT>)
2024-01-15 09:43:33         EXT HTTP PREFIXES:        <empty> (<DEFAULT>)
2024-01-15 09:43:33         ENABLE TRUSTED AUTH:      False (<DEFAULT>)
2024-01-15 09:43:33         ADD INTERFACE PREFIXES:   True (<DEFAULT>)
2024-01-15 09:43:33         CERTIFICATE STORE LOCATION: <empty> (<DEFAULT>)
2024-01-15 09:43:33         CERTIFICATE STORE NAME:   <empty> (<DEFAULT>)
2024-01-15 09:43:33         CERTIFICATE SUBJECT NAME: <empty> (<DEFAULT>)
2024-01-15 09:43:33         CERTIFICATE THUMBPRINT:   <empty> (<DEFAULT>)
2024-01-15 09:43:33         CERTIFICATE FILE:         <empty> (<DEFAULT>)
2024-01-15 09:43:33         CERTIFICATE PASSWORD:     <empty> (<DEFAULT>)
[01284,01,07:45:54.938]
2024-01-15 09:45:55 "ES VERSION:"             "5.0.10.0" ("oss-v5.0.10"/"6b9af2bc4fcd85c12c01fb115110ff6ccc5d3bfd", "Thu, 11 Mar 2021 14:39:
2024-01-15 09:45:55 08 +0100")
2024-01-15 09:45:55 MODIFIED OPTIONS:
2024-01-15 09:45:55 
2024-01-15 09:45:55         EXT HTTP PORT:            2114 (Command Line)
2024-01-15 09:45:55         EXT TCP PORT:             1114 (Command Line)
2024-01-15 09:45:55 
2024-01-15 09:45:55 DEFAULT OPTIONS:
2024-01-15 09:45:55 
2024-01-15 09:45:55         HELP:                     False (<DEFAULT>)
2024-01-15 09:45:55         VERSION:                  False (<DEFAULT>)
2024-01-15 09:45:55         LOG:                      C:\EventStore\logs (<DEFAULT>) 
2024-01-15 09:45:55         CONFIG:                   <empty> (<DEFAULT>)
2024-01-15 09:45:55         DEFINES:                  <empty> (<DEFAULT>)
2024-01-15 09:45:55         WHAT IF:                  False (<DEFAULT>)
2024-01-15 09:45:55         START STANDARD PROJECTIONS: False (<DEFAULT>)
2024-01-15 09:45:55         DISABLE HTTP CACHING:     False (<DEFAULT>)
2024-01-15 09:45:55         MONO MIN THREADPOOL SIZE: 10 (<DEFAULT>)
2024-01-15 09:45:55         INT IP:                   127.0.0.1 (<DEFAULT>)
2024-01-15 09:45:55         EXT IP:                   127.0.0.1 (<DEFAULT>)
2024-01-15 09:45:55         INT HTTP PORT:            2112 (<DEFAULT>)
2024-01-15 09:45:55         INT TCP PORT:             1112 (<DEFAULT>)
2024-01-15 09:45:55         INT SECURE TCP PORT:      0 (<DEFAULT>)
2024-01-15 09:45:55         EXT SECURE TCP PORT ADVERTISE AS: 0 (<DEFAULT>)
2024-01-15 09:45:55         EXT SECURE TCP PORT:      0 (<DEFAULT>)
2024-01-15 09:45:55         EXT IP ADVERTISE AS:      <empty> (<DEFAULT>)
2024-01-15 09:45:55         EXT TCP PORT ADVERTISE AS: 0 (<DEFAULT>)
2024-01-15 09:45:55         EXT HTTP PORT ADVERTISE AS: 0 (<DEFAULT>)
2024-01-15 09:45:55         INT IP ADVERTISE AS:      <empty> (<DEFAULT>)
2024-01-15 09:45:55         INT SECURE TCP PORT ADVERTISE AS: 0 (<DEFAULT>)
2024-01-15 09:45:55         INT TCP PORT ADVERTISE AS: 0 (<DEFAULT>)
2024-01-15 09:45:55         INT HTTP PORT ADVERTISE AS: 0 (<DEFAULT>)
2024-01-15 09:45:55         INT TCP HEARTBEAT TIMEOUT: 700 (<DEFAULT>)
2024-01-15 09:45:55         EXT TCP HEARTBEAT TIMEOUT: 1000 (<DEFAULT>)
2024-01-15 09:45:55         INT TCP HEARTBEAT INTERVAL: 700 (<DEFAULT>)
2024-01-15 09:45:55         EXT TCP HEARTBEAT INTERVAL: 2000 (<DEFAULT>)
2024-01-15 09:45:55         GOSSIP ON SINGLE NODE:    False (<DEFAULT>)
2024-01-15 09:45:55         CONNECTION PENDING SEND BYTES THRESHOLD: 10485760 (<DEFAULT>)
2024-01-15 09:45:55         CONNECTION QUEUE SIZE THRESHOLD: 50000 (<DEFAULT>)
2024-01-15 09:45:55         STREAM INFO CACHE CAPACITY: 100000 (<DEFAULT>)
2024-01-15 09:45:55         FORCE:                    False (<DEFAULT>)
2024-01-15 09:45:55         CLUSTER SIZE:             1 (<DEFAULT>)
2024-01-15 09:45:55         NODE PRIORITY:            0 (<DEFAULT>)
2024-01-15 09:45:55         MIN FLUSH DELAY MS:       2 (<DEFAULT>)
2024-01-15 09:45:55         COMMIT COUNT:             -1 (<DEFAULT>)
2024-01-15 09:45:55         PREPARE COUNT:            -1 (<DEFAULT>)
2024-01-15 09:45:55         ADMIN ON EXT:             True (<DEFAULT>)
2024-01-15 09:45:55         STATS ON EXT:             True (<DEFAULT>)
2024-01-15 09:45:55         GOSSIP ON EXT:            True (<DEFAULT>)
2024-01-15 09:45:55         DISABLE SCAVENGE MERGING: False (<DEFAULT>)
2024-01-15 09:45:55         SCAVENGE HISTORY MAX AGE: 30 (<DEFAULT>)
2024-01-15 09:45:55         DISCOVER VIA DNS:         True (<DEFAULT>)
2024-01-15 09:45:55         CLUSTER DNS:              fake.dns (<DEFAULT>)
2024-01-15 09:45:55         CLUSTER GOSSIP PORT:      30777 (<DEFAULT>)
2024-01-15 09:45:55         GOSSIP SEED:              <empty> (<DEFAULT>)
2024-01-15 09:45:55         STATS PERIOD SEC:         30 (<DEFAULT>)
2024-01-15 09:45:55         CACHED CHUNKS:            -1 (<DEFAULT>)
2024-01-15 09:45:55         READER THREADS COUNT:     4 (<DEFAULT>)
2024-01-15 09:45:55         CHUNKS CACHE SIZE:        536871424 (<DEFAULT>)
2024-01-15 09:45:55         MAX MEM TABLE SIZE:       1000000 (<DEFAULT>)
2024-01-15 09:45:55         HASH COLLISION READ LIMIT: 100 (<DEFAULT>)
2024-01-15 09:45:55         DB:                       C:\EventStore\data (<DEFAULT>)
2024-01-15 09:45:55         INDEX:                    <empty> (<DEFAULT>)
2024-01-15 09:45:55         MEM DB:                   False (<DEFAULT>)
2024-01-15 09:45:55         SKIP DB VERIFY:           False (<DEFAULT>)
2024-01-15 09:45:55         WRITE THROUGH:            False (<DEFAULT>)
2024-01-15 09:45:55         UNBUFFERED:               False (<DEFAULT>)
2024-01-15 09:45:55         CHUNK INITIAL READER COUNT: 5 (<DEFAULT>)
2024-01-15 09:45:55         RUN PROJECTIONS:          None (<DEFAULT>)
2024-01-15 09:45:55         PROJECTION THREADS:       3 (<DEFAULT>)
2024-01-15 09:45:55         WORKER THREADS:           5 (<DEFAULT>)
2024-01-15 09:45:55         PROJECTIONS QUERY EXPIRY: 5 (<DEFAULT>)
i024-01-15 09:45:55         FAULT OUT OF ORDER PROJECTIONS: False (<DEFAULT>)
2024-01-15 09:45:55         INT HTTP PREFIXES:        <empty> (<DEFAULT>)
2024-01-15 09:45:55         EXT HTTP PREFIXES:        <empty> (<DEFAULT>)
2024-01-15 09:45:55         ENABLE TRUSTED AUTH:      False (<DEFAULT>)
2024-01-15 09:45:55         ADD INTERFACE PREFIXES:   True (<DEFAULT>)
2024-01-15 09:45:55         CERTIFICATE STORE LOCATION: <empty> (<DEFAULT>)
2024-01-15 09:45:55         CERTIFICATE STORE NAME:   <empty> (<DEFAULT>)
2024-01-15 09:45:55         CERTIFICATE SUBJECT NAME: <empty> (<DEFAULT>)
2024-01-15 09:45:55         CERTIFICATE THUMBPRINT:   <empty> (<DEFAULT>)
2024-01-15 09:45:55         CERTIFICATE FILE:         <empty> (<DEFAULT>)
2024-01-15 09:45:55         CERTIFICATE PASSWORD:     <empty> (<DEFAULT>)
2024-01-15 09:45:55         USE INTERNAL SSL:         False (<DEFAULT>)
[024-01-15 09:45:55         DISABLE INSECURE TCP:     False (<DEFAULT>)
2024-01-15 09:45:55         SSL TARGET HOST:          n/a (<DEFAULT>)
2024-01-15 09:45:55         SSL VALIDATE SERVER:      True (<DEFAULT>)
2024-01-15 09:45:55         AUTHENTICATION TYPE:      internal (<DEFAULT>)
2024-01-15 09:45:55         AUTHENTICATION CONFIG:    <empty> (<DEFAULT>)
2024-01-15 09:45:55         DISABLE FIRST LEVEL HTTP AUTHORIZATION: False (<DEFAULT>)
2024-01-15 09:45:55         PREPARE TIMEOUT MS:       2000 (<DEFAULT>)
2024-01-15 09:45:55         COMMIT TIMEOUT MS:        2000 (<DEFAULT>)
2024-01-15 09:45:55         UNSAFE DISABLE FLUSH TO DISK: False (<DEFAULT>)
2024-01-15 09:45:55         BETTER ORDERING:          False (<DEFAULT>)
2024-01-15 09:45:55         UNSAFE IGNORE HARD DELETE: False (<DEFAULT>)
2024-01-15 09:45:55         SKIP INDEX VERIFY:        False (<DEFAULT>)
2024-01-15 09:45:55         INDEX CACHE DEPTH:        16 (<DEFAULT>)
2024-01-15 09:45:55         OPTIMIZE INDEX MERGE:     False (<DEFAULT>)
2024-01-15 09:45:55         GOSSIP INTERVAL MS:       1000 (<DEFAULT>)
2024-01-15 09:45:55         GOSSIP ALLOWED DIFFERENCE MS: 60000 (<DEFAULT>)
2024-01-15 09:45:55         GOSSIP TIMEOUT MS:        500 (<DEFAULT>)
[01284,01,07:45:55.891] Opened ongoing "C:\EventStore\data\chunk-000000.000000" as version 3 "0","IntHttpPortAdvertiseAs
[01284,01,07:45:55.906] CACHED TFChunk #0-0 (chunk-000000.000000) in 00:00:00.0047455. 
[01284,01,07:45:56.208] Starting MiniWeb for "/web/es/js/projections" ==> "C:\EventStore\projections" 
[01284,01,07:45:56.208] Starting MiniWeb for "/web/es/js/projections/v8/Prelude" ==> "C:\EventStore\Prelude" 
2024-01-15 09:45:56 [01284,01,07:45:56.224] Starting MiniWeb for "/web" ==> "C:\EventStore\clusternode-web"
2024-01-15 09:45:56 [01284,01,07:45:56.224] Binding MiniWeb to "/web/{*remaining_path}"
2024-01-15 09:45:56 [01284,10,07:45:56.224] ========== [127.0.0.1:2112] SYSTEM INIT...
[01284,11,07:45:56.224] TableIndex initialization... 
2024-01-15 09:45:56 [01284,10,07:45:56.239] Starting "Normal" TCP listening on TCP endpoint: 127.0.0.1:1114.
[01284,11,07:45:56.255] ReadIndex building... 
[01284,10,07:45:56.271] Starting HTTP server on ["http://localhost:2114/,http://127.0.0.1:2114/"]... 
2024-01-15 09:45:56 df60f5a835d}](L=2413,W=18903,C=18903,E3@2191:{5d193532-91ce-4d8f-8fc2-5fd0fb67c25a})".
[01284,06,07:49:45.474] Segments count: 1, buffers count: 20, should be when full: 20 TE, WAITING FOR CHASER TO CATCH UP...
2024-01-15 09:45:56 [01284,10,07:45:56.333] ========== [127.0.0.1:2112] IS MASTER... SPARTA!
2024-01-15 09:45:56 [01284,05,07:45:56.333] Persistent subscriptions received state change to PreMaster. Stopping listening
2024-01-15 09:45:56 [01284,10,07:45:56.333] Searching for incomplete scavenges on node "127.0.0.1:2114".
2024-01-15 09:45:56 [01284,05,07:45:56.333] Persistent subscriptions Became Master so now handling subscriptions
[01284,08,07:45:56.364] === Writing E4@18903:{e90dcaee-48f5-4147-a3c7-f51867b47158} (previous epoch at 2191). 
2024-01-15 09:45:56 [01284,10,07:45:56.364] Max age and $ops read permission already set for the "$scavenges" stream.
2024-01-15 09:45:56 [01284,10,07:45:56.364] No incomplete scavenges found on node "127.0.0.1:2114".
2024-01-15 09:45:56 [01284,13,07:45:56.364] PROJECTIONS: Starting Projections Core Coordinator. (Node State : Master)
2024-01-15 09:45:56 [01284,13,07:45:56.364] PROJECTIONS: Starting Projections Manager. (Node State : Master)
2024-01-15 09:45:56 [01284,13,07:45:56.364] PROJECTIONS: Resetting Worker Writer
2024-01-15 09:45:56 [01284,10,07:45:56.364] ========== [127.0.0.1:2112] Sub System '"Projections"' initialized.
2024-01-15 09:45:56 [01284,13,07:45:56.364] PROJECTIONS: SubComponent Started: "EventReaderCoreService"
2024-01-15 09:45:56 [01284,08,07:45:56.364] === Update Last Epoch E4@18903:{e90dcaee-48f5-4147-a3c7-f51867b47158} (previous epoch at 2191). 
[01284,05,07:45:56.896] Created stats stream '"$stats-127.0.0.1:2114"', code = WrongExpectedVersion
```

My network section of the inspect :

```
{
    "Id": "ea78d3363fc2f9a3cc5e1b67c55772f67e3e63cf724636e691a8210b06c5e922",
    "Created": "2024-01-15T07:43:19.5805765Z",
    "Path": "EventStore.ClusterNode.exe",
    "Args": [
        "--ext-http-port",
        "2114",
        "--ext-tcp-port",
        "1114"
    ],
    "State": {
        "Status": "running",
        "Running": true,
        "Paused": false,
        "Restarting": false,
        "OOMKilled": false,
        "Dead": false,
        "Pid": 1284,
        "ExitCode": 0,
        "Error": "",
        "StartedAt": "2024-01-15T07:45:53.7466139Z",
        "FinishedAt": "2024-01-15T09:44:33.5226551+02:00"
    },
    "Image": "sha256:c31ae93c602f572270469ed1e09e0f391d6b95147498d617f2fb46230a922ee1",
    "ResolvConfPath": "",
    "HostnamePath": "",
    "HostsPath": "",
    "LogPath": "C:\\ProgramData\\Docker\\containers\\ea78d3363fc2f9a3cc5e1b67c55772f67e3e63cf724636e691a8210b06c5e922\\ea78d3363fc2f9a3cc5e1b67c55772f67e3e63cf724636e691a8210b06c5e922-json.log",
    "Name": "/eventstore-node",
    "RestartCount": 0,
    "Driver": "windowsfilter",
    "Platform": "windows",
    "MountLabel": "",
    "ProcessLabel": "",
    "AppArmorProfile": "",
    "ExecIDs": [
        "2c31d86df3bab58cee2594e3897f744d81e1a208c82c0f2b673a7e7a88269a4d"
    ],
    "HostConfig": {
        "Binds": null,
        "ContainerIDFile": "",
        "LogConfig": {
            "Type": "json-file",
            "Config": {}
        },
        "NetworkMode": "default",
        "PortBindings": {
            "1113/tcp": [
                {
                    "HostIp": "",
                    "HostPort": "1113"
                }
            ],
            "2113/tcp": [
                {
                    "HostIp": "",
                    "HostPort": "2113"
                }
            ]
        },
        "RestartPolicy": {
            "Name": "no",
            "MaximumRetryCount": 0
        },
        "AutoRemove": false,
        "VolumeDriver": "",
        "VolumesFrom": null,
        "ConsoleSize": [
            30,
            120
        ],
        "CapAdd": null,
        "CapDrop": null,
        "CgroupnsMode": "",
        "Dns": [],
        "DnsOptions": [],
        "DnsSearch": [],
        "ExtraHosts": null,
        "GroupAdd": null,
        "IpcMode": "",
        "Cgroup": "",
        "Links": null,
        "OomScoreAdj": 0,
        "PidMode": "",
        "Privileged": false,
        "PublishAllPorts": false,
        "ReadonlyRootfs": false,
        "SecurityOpt": null,
        "UTSMode": "",
        "UsernsMode": "",
        "ShmSize": 0,
        "Isolation": "hyperv",
        "CpuShares": 0,
        "Memory": 0,
        "NanoCpus": 0,
        "CgroupParent": "",
        "BlkioWeight": 0,
        "BlkioWeightDevice": [],
        "BlkioDeviceReadBps": [],
        "BlkioDeviceWriteBps": [],
        "BlkioDeviceReadIOps": [],
        "BlkioDeviceWriteIOps": [],
        "CpuPeriod": 0,
        "CpuQuota": 0,
        "CpuRealtimePeriod": 0,
        "CpuRealtimeRuntime": 0,
        "CpusetCpus": "",
        "CpusetMems": "",
        "Devices": [],
        "DeviceCgroupRules": null,
        "DeviceRequests": null,
        "MemoryReservation": 0,
        "MemorySwap": 0,
        "MemorySwappiness": null,
        "OomKillDisable": false,
        "PidsLimit": null,
        "Ulimits": null,
        "CpuCount": 0,
        "CpuPercent": 0,
        "IOMaximumIOps": 0,
        "IOMaximumBandwidth": 0,
        "MaskedPaths": null,
        "ReadonlyPaths": null
    },
    "GraphDriver": {
        "Data": {
            "dir": "C:\\ProgramData\\Docker\\windowsfilter\\ea78d3363fc2f9a3cc5e1b67c55772f67e3e63cf724636e691a8210b06c5e922"
        },
        "Name": "windowsfilter"
    },
    "Mounts": [],
    "Config": {
        "Hostname": "ea78d3363fc2",
        "Domainname": "",
        "User": "",
        "AttachStdin": true,
        "AttachStdout": true,
        "AttachStderr": true,
        "ExposedPorts": {
            "1113/tcp": {},
            "2113/tcp": {}
        },
        "Tty": true,
        "OpenStdin": true,
        "StdinOnce": true,
        "Env": null,
        "Cmd": [
            "EventStore.ClusterNode.exe",
            "--ext-http-port",
            "2114",
            "--ext-tcp-port",
            "1114"
        ],
        "Image": "eventstore_5.0.10:latest",
        "Volumes": null,
        "WorkingDir": "C:\\EventStore",
        "Entrypoint": null,
        "OnBuild": null,
        "Labels": {}
    },
    "NetworkSettings": {
        "Bridge": "",
        "SandboxID": "ea78d3363fc2f9a3cc5e1b67c55772f67e3e63cf724636e691a8210b06c5e922",
        "HairpinMode": false,
        "LinkLocalIPv6Address": "",
        "LinkLocalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
        "Ports": {
            "1113/tcp": [
                {
                    "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
                    "HostPort": "1113"
                }
            ],
            "2113/tcp": [
                {
                    "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
                    "HostPort": "2113"
                }
            ]
        },
        "SandboxKey": "ea78d3363fc2f9a3cc5e1b67c55772f67e3e63cf724636e691a8210b06c5e922",
        "SecondaryIPAddresses": null,
        "SecondaryIPv6Addresses": null,
        "EndpointID": "",
        "Gateway": "",
        "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
        "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
        "IPAddress": "",
        "IPPrefixLen": 0,
        "IPv6Gateway": "",
        "MacAddress": "",
        "Networks": {
            "nat": {
                "IPAMConfig": null,
                "Links": null,
                "Aliases": null,
                "NetworkID": "9b278c35599d8de2a001da51c4ef9fe663f908163861792bba7610bcf7f9c887",
                "EndpointID": "0da7da9dff1d4e7861bf3cb13e91181e56a8797de25de612643ea6437379e3bc",
                "Gateway": "172.29.240.1",
                "IPAddress": "172.29.254.94",
                "IPPrefixLen": 16,
                "IPv6Gateway": "",
                "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
                "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
                "MacAddress": "00:15:5d:7a:a9:ee",
                "DriverOpts": null
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I run a curl on the container, I get a happy response :

```
C:\EventStore>curl -I localhost:2114
HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed
Content-Length: 0
Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, X-Requested-With, X-Forwarded-Host, X-Forwarded-Prefix, X-PINGOTHER, Authorization, ES-LongPoll, ES-ExpectedVersion, ES-EventId, ES-EventType, ES-RequiresMaster, ES-HardDelete, ES-Resolv
eLinkTos
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Location, ES-Position, ES-CurrentVersion
Date: Mon, 15 Jan 2024 08:01:53 GMT
```

When I try curl'ing to the IP from the network section, or localhost on my host, I get the following response :

```
C:\EventStoreDocker>curl -I http://172.29.254.94:2113
curl: (28) Failed to connect to 172.29.254.94 port 2113 after 21028 ms: Couldn't connect to server

C:\EventStoreDocker>curl -I http://localhost:2113
curl: (28) Failed to connect to localhost port 2113 after 21261 ms: Couldn't connect to server

C:\EventStoreDocker>curl -I http://127.0.0.1:2113
curl: (28) Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 2113 after 21052 ms: Couldn't connect to server
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was the docker container was never running in secure mode:

Changing the docker-compose to this fixed the problem :

```
...
- EVENTSTORE_INSECURE=true
- EVENTSTORE_DISABLE_INTERNAL_TCP_TLS=true
- EVENTSTORE_DISABLE_EXTERNAL_TCP_TLS=true
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to create your own image?

Try this docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3.4"

services:
  eventstore.db:
    image: eventstore/eventstore:23.10.0-bookworm-slim
    environment:
      - EVENTSTORE_CLUSTER_SIZE=1
      - EVENTSTORE_RUN_PROJECTIONS=All
      - EVENTSTORE_START_STANDARD_PROJECTIONS=true
      - EVENTSTORE_EXT_TCP_PORT=1113
      - EVENTSTORE_HTTP_PORT=2113
      - EVENTSTORE_INSECURE=true
      - EVENTSTORE_ENABLE_EXTERNAL_TCP=true
      - EVENTSTORE_ENABLE_ATOM_PUB_OVER_HTTP=true
    ports:
      - "1113:1113"
      - "2113:2113"
    volumes:
      - type: volume
        source: eventstore-volume-data
        target: /var/lib/eventstore
      - type: volume
        source: eventstore-volume-logs
        target: /var/log/eventstore

volumes:
  eventstore-volume-data:
  eventstore-volume-logs:
```

Comment: I have dependencies that are not compatible with the latest ES. I need to stick to 5.0.10

Comment: Ok.
In your docker-compose.yml you are using eventstore/eventstore:release-v5 image and not your custom eventstore_5.0.10:latest.